# How to start animation from special frame

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm new to Unity. I use the last version of Unity, 5.1.2f1 Personal.

I want to start an animation from special frame. Not from first.

So I searched and get these answers;

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/181903/jump-to-a-specific-frame-in-an-animation.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/425985/set-the-current-time-frame-of-a-mecanim-animation.html

But in my project, it didn't work! And I spent my time for solve this problem a while.

Situation is this. I'm creating a Rockman(Megaman) game.

And I have to implement when the character Zero use his saber while falling,

the falling_shot animation starts from the frame.

Watch this picture to help you explain what I have to do.

[image]

It is simple question. If I can access each frame directly with Animation array's index,

what I have to do is just set the playing index to next frame's index. It's not hard.

But in Unity, I cannot access Animation components directly

and I found that I have to use operator this [] like;

```
// set start frame with time 0.5
animation["JumpShotA"].time = 0.5f;
```

However it didn't work. Here's my code that playing animation "JumpShotAir".

It's not the code that change animations frame, but just plays JumpShotAir animation.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ZController : MonoBehaviour {
    Animator _animator;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        var animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
        var jumpShotA = animation["JumpShotA"];
        animation.clip = jumpShotA.clip;
        animation.Play();
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    
    }
}
```

But this code results like this; message that NullReferenceException: GetRef error.

[image]

I really don't know. What did I wrong? Is there any problem in my code?

Can I access Animation component's array directly? How can I access it?

If you want to download my test project, check this out.

[Test project. Links to Google drive.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_piXOzIlhTsaXQ0MU1CeEhXVmc/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks for reading.

---

Unity window picture updated. Please check my mistake.

[image]

---

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gOzhNK6qjNQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I changed animation type to legacy but still problem exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that JumpShotA clip exist in your animations array in animation component of your `GameObject`. This error shows you have no reference for `JumpShotA` in animations array while you are trying to play it.

Comment: I uploaded my situation. Please check I made mistake. I think I added animation "JumpShotA" to animations array correctly..

Comment: Is your animation type set to legacy? if not set it to legacy and then try.

Comment: Nain // please check my movie? I changed animation type to legacy but problem is not fixed...

Comment: You are using animation.isPlaying check and in your animation component you have no reference to default animation so when you run your code no animation is playing at start thats why it is not playing . Put some Default animation and it will be fine :)

Comment: Nain // Actually, it didn't work either. I decide to use blend tree and call event handler "updateFrameIndex" every frame. I think I've found the information about this but, it seems like I have to stop searching this and wasting my time.
I really appreciate to you. You deserve this. Thanks.